# Change mysql column with button

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to change a mysql column, when I press a button.
My current code:

```
      <?php if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT type FROM users WHERE id_user = 2 ")) {

            $r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

            }
        print_r($r);

       if(isset($_POST['d'])){
       $sql = "UPDATE users SET type= 'd' WHERE id_user = 2 ";
       }
        ?>
        <input type="submit" value="d" name="d" />
```

I want to change of the column "type" which is set a by default, where the id = 2, but when I press the button, nothing happens. What have I done wrong in the if(isset()) ?

EDIT: SOLVED with all respondents:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['d'])){
$var = $_POST['d'];
$sql = "UPDATE users SET `type`= '$var'  WHERE id_user = 2 ";
$mysqli->query($sql) or die($mysqli->error);
}
if(isset($_POST['a'])){
$var = $_POST['a'];
$sql = "UPDATE users SET `type`= '$var'  WHERE id_user = 2 ";
$mysqli->query($sql) or die($mysqli->error);

}
?>
<form action="#" method="POST">
   <input type="text" value="d" name="d"/>
   <input type="submit" value="d"/>
</form>
<form action="#" method="POST">
   <input type="text" value="a" name="a"/>
   <input type="submit" value="a"/>
</form>


<?php

 if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT `type` FROM users WHERE id_user = 2 ")) {

    $r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    }
print_r($r);
print_r($_POST)
?>
```

Comment: Is this inside a `<form>` tag?  When you say "nothing happens" do you mean that nothing happens and the page stays as is, or that the page reloads but without the database action?

Comment: Yes it is. The only thing that changes, is my url with the end tag "?d=d". The print stays the same with a

Comment: Than you have a `$_GET` variable, not `$_POST`

Comment: I inserted the code below and it still stays the same. The page refreshs and the print hasn't changed. If I click on "refresh" manually, an alert pops up, that if I return, the action will be done again.. I am confused.

Comment: You're doing the `SELECT` query and printing the value before you do the update.  If you want the updated value to be printed, move the update before the `SELECT` and print.

Comment: still nothing happens.. check the chat of the answer below! there we are making progess

Comment: type is also the name of my column - do I have to write it like this in the code to change the column: `$sql = "UPDATE users SET `type`= 'd' WHERE id_user = 2 ";` or should I just rename the column?

Comment: @pr0cz I edited my post

Comment: Use a prepared statement and be done with it.

Comment: @PatrickQ Keywords don't need to be backticked, only reserved words https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html and there's no `(R)` next to that.

Comment: Whoever told you to use ticks inside POST arrays, was wrong. Assign a variable to it rather than inserting the POST array directly. Btw, did you ever close off that form? I don't see `</form>` anywhere.

Comment: @Fred-ii- okay, thank you! But how do I fight against `Unknown column 'a' in 'field list'` when I press the button? I am searching now for prepared statements, but I heard from this for the first time now :)

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['d'])) { $var = $_POST['d']; ... UPDATE users SET type = '$var'   WHERE... }` . It will be much easier if you used a prepared statement for this. Prepared statements mysqli http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: It works! Oh god, thank you so much!! I will try to learn about prepared statements! Never heard of it before. Thank you!

Comment: @pr0cz you're welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I stated in comments: (and besides other comments I left).

Assign a variable to it then pass it in the query and quote it.

```
if(isset($_POST['d'])) { 

  $var = $_POST['d']; ... UPDATE users SET type = '$var' WHERE... 

}
```

But do learn to use prepared statements, since you are open to an sql injection:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the variable in the query like this and print out the value of your select statement inside the `if` clause. Furthermore as @Patrick Q mentioned `TYPE` is a mysql keyword and must be enclosed in backticks:

PHP:

```
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT `type` FROM users WHERE id_user = 2 ")) {
    $r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    print_r($r);
}

if(isset($_POST['d'])) {
    $sql = "UPDATE users SET `type`= '" . $_POST['d'] . "' WHERE id_user = 2 ";
    $mysqli->query($sql);
}
```

HTML:

```
<form action="#" method="POST">
   <input type="text" value="d" name="d"/>
   <input type="submit" value="d"/>
</form>
```

Pay attention that you really use `POST` as the method of the form and not `GET`.

Comment: I will try it! Thanks!

Comment: I inserted the code and it still stays the same. The page refreshs and the print hasn't changed. If I click on "refresh" manually, an alert pops up, that if I return, the action will be done again.. I am confused.

Comment: @pr0cz I do not quite understand your first query (select). Why do you do this at all?

Comment: just to see, what type is already set. So if there are a couple of accounts listed, too see which one is a and which one is d

Comment: Nah. I click on the button and my URL only adds a "#" now.

Comment: @pr0cz Yes that's correct if you use post. Do you try to use `print_r($_POST)` to see what's in `$_POST`?

Comment: The array in print_r($_POST) changes correctly! But not the mysql coloumn.

Comment: @pr0cz Have you considered that the database connection is set correctly? And do you check whether `isset($_POST['d'])` returns `true`?

Comment: The database connection is correct, because the `print_r($r)` does sho the right value. I will check the `isset($_POST['d'])`.

Comment: @pr0cz Is the update query executed? Did you check this?

Comment: It shows me these `Array ( [type] => a ) Array ( [d] => d )` , I added a button to change the array back to a, then this happens : `Array ( [type] => a ) Array ( [a] => a )`

Comment: @pr0cz You do the query to print the value before you do the update, so it's showing the old value.

Comment: @Barmar @rbr94  yea, but if I refresh the page, it still shows the old value a and the `Array ( [d] => d )` will go empty to `Array()`, it doesn't switch to d.

Comment: @pr0cz Then you need to switch the select and the update query as Barmar suggested. If you want to get the new value instead of the old.

Comment: @rbr94 I already did. First is the update query followed by the select.

Comment: Check for errors from the `UPDATE` query: `$mysqli->query($sql) or die($mysqli->error);`

Comment: @pr0cz Do you use the  backticks for the type column like I suggested in my post above?

Comment: @rbr94 yea, but not IN the column at the mysql table. Shall I just write ` `d` `into my column with my mysql workbench?

Comment: @pr0cz No, just do as I suggested.